# CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message)

Tags: yolo, cmake-gui, darknet

I am trying to use cmake to compile darknet for YOLO V3. But I'm getting following error:

> CMake Error at C:/Program
>   Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146
>   (message):   Could NOT find PThreads_windows (missing:
>   PThreads_windows_LIBRARY   PThreads_windows_INCLUDE_DIR) Call Stack
>   (most recent call first):   C:/Program
>   Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:393
>   (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)   cmake/Modules/FindPThreads_windows.cmake:39
>   (find_package_handle_standard_args)
>   C:/Users/MSI/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:288
>   (_find_package)   CMakeLists.txt:93 (find_package)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You have defined CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE as vcpkg. If this variable is defined, darknet will by default think that you have configured pthread_window in vcpkg (it happens at around 30 ~40 lines in CMakeLists.txt), but you actually not.
So you need to replace

```
if(WIN32 AND NOT DEFINED CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE)
  set(USE_INTEGRATED_LIBS "TRUE" CACHE BOOL "Use libs distributed with this repo")
else()
  set(USE_INTEGRATED_LIBS "FALSE" CACHE BOOL "Use libs distributed with this repo")
endif()
```

by

```
set(USE_INTEGRATED_LIBS "TRUE" CACHE BOOL "Use libs distributed with this repo")
```

It will allow darknet to use its own 3rdparty pthreads in the root directory.